# Exporting Layers to Files Without Losing the Effects in Photoshop CS6

Tags: layers, export, effects, cs6

Here is the problem. I am doing this work for a company. They wanted me to clean 138 jpeg files and give them back.

I opened a psd and put all the files in it. I cleaned all of them. At last, i created 2 effects. 1 Brightness/contrast and 1 curves. They are at the top of the layers.

Then i tried "File>Scripts>Export Layers to Files" command. Here comes the problem. This command closes all the layers first, just let one open, save it, and then goes for another one.

But in this time, my Brightness/contrast and Curves layers are also closing. So i cannot see these effects on layers.

Anyone has a suggestion about this?

Comment: Do you know how to script using javascript, applescript, or vbscript?

Answer (score 4):

So it's just two adjustment layers you need to add? I'd create an action to add them, then use a batch (File → Automate → Batch) to process all the original files. You can include a Save For Web command in the Action to save them to a known location, as well.

Should be a fairly quick job to set up, and it also shouldn't take long to stomp through 138 or even 1380 files.

Here's a video on batch processing from Adobe:
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/understanding-adobe-photoshop-cs6/batch-processing/

Answer (score 0):

If you export every layer separately the composition is lost since the brightness/contrast is its own layer. You could use layer comps and then script export the compositions. Or, make a smart object from the settings layer and the image layer, then script export every layer.